# Force CMake to generate zsh friendly command lines

Tags: bash, cmake, zsh, oh-my-zsh

I have a CMake such that when I executed the build (make) in verbose mode, it prints commands such as:

```
/usr/bin/nvcc -forward-unknown-to-host-compiler -DBOOST_ALL_NO_LIB -DBOOST_CHRONO_DYN_LINK -DBOOST_PP_VARIADICS -DBOOST_TIMER_DYN_LINK -DBOOST_UNIT_TEST_FRAMEWORK_DYN_LINK  --expt-relaxed-constexpr --extended-lambda -Xcudafe "--display_error_number --diag_suppress=implicit_return_from_non_void_function --diag_suppress=class_and_member_name_conflict" --generate-code=arch=compute_61,code=[compute_61,sm_61] -std=c++17 -x cu -c /home/correaa/prj/alf/boost/multi/adaptors/thrust/test/array.cu -o CMakeFiles/array.cu.x.dir/array.cu.o
```

presumably, this is a bash-compatible command because I have no problem running it in bash.
However it is not a valid zsh command (the shell I use) because it gives an error:

```
zsh: no matches found: --generate-code=arch=compute_61,code=[compute_61,sm_61]
```

I presume it is the square brackets that trip zsh `[...]`.

**First question is how can I correct manually this command to run on both zsh and bash?**

**Second question is, is there a way to for CMake to generate makefiles that contain commands that are compatible with zsh?**

Comment: "I presume it is the square brackets that trip zsh" - It is easy to check: just paste the full command into zsh terminal and run it.

Comment: The line before "I presume" is the output from zsh. Digging more I realize it is not the `[...]` but the (double?) `=`.

Comment: Look up the NOMATCH option.

Comment: (You'd have the same issue on bash if its `failglob` option is turned on)

Comment: `--generate-code=arch=compute_61,code=[compute_61,sm_61]` is as wrong in `bash` or any shell where `[...]` is a glob operator as it in bash. At least `zsh` is nice enough to point out the problem to you.

Comment: @StephaneChazelas, I see. In that case it is a bug in CMake or in the nvcc command line options to generate such pattern.

Comment: Yes, `[...]`, `?` and `*` (and there can be more depending on the shell) are glob operators. They should be quoted to as to be taken literally. bash has that misfeature inherited from the Bourne shell that globs that don't match are passed as is instead of causing an error.